# Germany: Social Security contributions withdrawal rules

Tags: germany, social-security, pension

As I'm planning to move back to India, can you please clarify below the doubts I have about Social Security contributions withdrawal?

Q1. I have been contributing to Social Security consistently since December 2013.

Q2.1 Currently I have a *Niederlassungserlaubnis.* Can I still get back the money or need to wait until I am 67 years old? Somebody told me that once I get this kind of visa it's not possible to get back the money immediately.

Q.2.2 If I stay more than 5 years here, can I still get back the money? Again I got information that after 5 years it's not possible to get it until the age of 67.

Q.2.3. How do I apply for this amount withdrawal from India?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible. You have to wait 24 months and waive your right to a German pension, then you can get back the money you paid into Social Security (but not the part that was contributed by your employer, so essentially half of what was paid) - source: https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/Allgemein/de/Inhalt/Allgemeines/FAQ/International/erstattung_deutsche_versicherungsbeitraege/00_faq_liste_erstattung_deutsche_versicherungsbeitraege.html