# Germany: Social Security contributions withdrawal rules < 60 contributions or < 60 of stay

Tags: germany, pension

We were in Germany for 61 months but my pension contributions is only for 56 months.

can you clarify in this case if I will get back full pension money ?

Also why I don't get my employer's contributions as my employer has paid to the government on my behalf, if I wasn't working then my employer wouldn't have paid to German government.

Isn't this day light robbery by German government ?

Do you recommend any service from Germany who can help me getting back money to India ?

Comment: Why should anyone but the employer get back the employer’s contributions? Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13985/germany-social-security-contributions-withdrawal-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't this day light robbery by German government ?

No, since the German government doesn't recieve the money at all (it only gives a financial garantie).

> Do you recommend any service from Germany who can help me getting back money to India ?

Yes, contact the [Deutsche Rentenversicherung - Beitrags-Erstattung](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/DRV/LS/Beitrags-Erstattung/Beitrags-Erstattung_node.html) that recieves the money.

This will only be generally possible if no treaty exists about the transfer of pension contributions between the 2 countries.

You can apply for a **Versicherungsverlauf**, which will list all of your contributions which may be usefull later.

It seems that a treaty with India exists (see page [Deutsche Rentenversicherung - Homepage - Arbeiten in Deutschland und in Indien](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Broschueren/international/weitere_abkommen/39_arbeiten_deutschland_indien.html)).

The information there also suggests that applications for refunds (if you are eligible, which seems to be possible under certain conditions) can be made directly at a German consulate.

Having the **Versicherungsverlauf** when contacting the consulate would simplify any application, since all relevant information is contained in the document.

> Also why I don't get my employer's contributions as my employer has paid to the government on my behalf, if I wasn't working then my employer wouldn't have paid to German government.

The employer didn't pay on your behalf, it's part of **their** contribution to the pension system.

Any refund will be based on your contributions, not thoses of others.

---

**Sources**:

- [Deutsche Rentenversicherung - Beitrags-Erstattung](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/DRV/LS/Beitrags-Erstattung/Beitrags-Erstattung_node.html)

  - [Deutsche Rentenversicherung - Ansprechpartner & Verbindungsstellen - Indien - Arbeiten in Deutschland und Indien](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/DRV/DE/Rente/Ausland/Ansprechpartner-und-Verbindungsstellen/Indien/Indien.htm)
  - [Deutsche Rentenversicherung - Homepage - Arbeiten in Deutschland und in Indien](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Broschueren/international/weitere_abkommen/39_arbeiten_deutschland_indien.html)
- [Deutsche Rentenversicherung - FAQs - Versicherungsverlauf](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/DRV/DE/Rente/Allgemeine-Informationen/Wissenswertes-zur-Rente/FAQs/Versicherung/Versicherungsverlauf_Liste.html#4d27b143-3049-4db8-a041-468f420a420c)

  - [Online-Dienste der Deutschen Rentenversicherung](https://www.eservice-drv.de/SelfServiceWeb/)

    - select **Versicherungsverlauf**
    - enter **Versicherungsnummer (Insurance number**)
    - enter **last** and **first** name
    - press **Absenden** (Send)

**Note**: The Online services assumes your present address is known.
If this is not the case, fill out and send back the [pdf form V0150](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/SharedDocs/Formulare/DE/_pdf/V0150.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3) informing them of your present address. The PDF contains all possible addresses. Choose the one nearest to where you lived last.

A short letter, with the above information, asking for a **Versicherungsverlauf** will result in one being sent back to you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed info, kindly clarify if the communication needs to be in Deutsch or English is fine as well ?

Comment: @vikramvi Accourding to the PDF, when applying at a German Consulate you can do it in your native language. So English will also be possible. If you apply directly (online), English will probably also be an option. Look and see if you have your insurance number somewhere, since that will make things simpler.

Comment: I checked the links shared but didn't find "Versicherungsverlauf", can you please clarify on which page is this ? I'm using Chrome to translate German to English language.

Comment: @vikramvi Added link to answer. Hint: use the search box with such terms. In this case the FAQ was the first result.

Comment: Do you know any service provider who can help me get pension money, I'm having hard time translating German to English, also online application option is not available in 21st century as well

Comment: @vikramvi An online application is available, you just can't find it - so your conclusions are (again) false. I have added the information to the end of the answer. It is doubful that any (legitimate) service provider exists, since everythig is automatic when your address is known. As stated in the answer, the German Consulate will assist you when needed (especially where language is a problem).

Comment: You can apply in English, but they will answer in German by post. There are also services that will take care of the pension refund for you, but if you speak German, you can totally do it yourself. Here's an additional source with more information: https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/pension-payments-refund