# From Blue card holder to being dependent

Tags: germany, blue-card, dependent-visa, pension

My spouse is a blue card holder and we have been living in Germany for last 4.5 years. My kids and myself are living here in Germany as dependents . As a Blue card dependent I worked for 2.5 years for a company. My spouse is now asked to move to US (on L1A) in coming months.  I have a new job offer in Germany and the employer is supporting me to get my own blue card .

Can my spouse apply as a dependent of my blue card while he moves to US? If yes, Could you please guide me on the process?

Will this (change in visa status) affect his pension amount claim in case he/we decide to move back to our home country in future?

Highly appreciate your inputs.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The *pension amount claim* has nothing to do with any residence status. Once your spouse stops working, apply for a [Versicherungsverlauf](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/21493/17166), which will list all reported contributions. Your spouse can apply for a dependent visa if/when they return from the US (where they are a resident).